# Error: watch EMFILE when putting node_modules in /public

Tags: meteor

Supposedly, I'm supposed to put node_modules into /public in Meteor. This works fine, up until a point where I get a lot of files in the node_modules directory, and I start getting this error:

```
Error: watch EMFILE
    at errnoException (fs.js:648:11)
    at FSWatcher.start (fs.js:675:11)
    at Object.watch (fs.js:703:11)
    at [object Object]._scan (/usr/local/meteor/app/meteor/run.js:347:12)
    at /usr/local/meteor/app/meteor/run.js:362:14
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function.<anonymous> (/usr/local/meteor/app/lib/third/underscore.js:76:11)
    at [object Object]._scan (/usr/local/meteor/app/meteor/run.js:361:9)
    at /usr/local/meteor/app/meteor/run.js:362:14
    at Array.forEach (native)
```

How should I deal with this?

Answer (score 3):

This command solves it in linux :

```
sudo sh -c 'echo 8192 > /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_instances'
```

Comment: What is the equivalent of this on a Mac?

Comment: @MattiasPetterJohansson I think that well be:  ulimit -n 16384

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't work. But it lead me to this question and answer, which partially solved the issue:
http://superuser.com/questions/302754/increase-the-maximum-number-of-open-file-descriptors-in-snow-leopard