# How to prevent Meteor from watching files?

Tags: dojo, meteor

I would like to use [Dojo Toolkit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dojo_Toolkit) with [Meteor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meteor_%28platform%29).

1. I first copy the whole Dojo Toolkit tree in `/public`
2. Then, I include it on the client side with:

   ```
   <script src="/dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="async: true"></script>`
   ```

Everything works fine, except Meteor is actually monitoring every single file in `/public` for changes, so that it can restart the server. This is actually causing a very long delay during the first request on `localhost:3000`.

Is there a way of preventing Meteor from watching files from a certain directory?

---

Dojo Toolkit is 10k+ files so I get the EMFILE error stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11300969/error-watch-emfile-when-putting-node-modules-in-public), corrected with

```
sudo sh -c 'echo 16384 > /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches'
```

Comment: I finally found a workaround. 
I'm putting everything in /public/lib/. 
Then, line 286 of /usr/lib/meteor/app/run.js,
I'm adding the folder I don't want Meteor to watch: 

`self.exclude_paths = [
    path.join(app_dir, '.meteor', 'local'),
    path.join(app_dir, 'public', 'lib')
];
`
This way I can have as much files as I want in lib, and they don't slow everything down.

include path is '/lib/dojo/dojo.js'.

Comment: nice fix, you should send them a patch and post this as an answer below

Comment: The workaround @Mathieu suggests should work fine for this purpose, but Meteor should support something like this natively. This is also filed as a GitHub Issue, which is the appropriate place to continue discussing this matter, or to track its resolution. https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/437

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15936091/turn-off-file-watching-in-meteor

Comment: @BjoernRennhak you know that the answer in the question you linked is in fact a quote from this topic right?

Comment: Can't hurt to link them or does it?

Comment: I don't have a `/usr/lib/meteor`. Running OS X and installed through the Meteor script.

Comment: Not sure if this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14823783/how-to-disable-hot-code-push-in-meteor-js-in-development

Answer (score 5):

realised this is duplicate to: [generating and serving static files with Meteor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13201723/generating-and-serving-static-files-with-meteor/20358612#20358612)

see: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/437

This was a major problem for me. I have to serve ~12000 static images, which I initially put into the public folder. This caused node to use nearly 100% of one CPU core, constantly. With limited memory the app crashes.

The workaround I'm using for the moment

- create the folder `public/.#static/` and move all static assets into it. This folder isn't watched by meteor
- prefix urls with static (`/img/cat.png -> /static/img/cat.png`)
- install the mime npm package

  ```
  cd ~/.meteor/tools/latest/lib/node_modules/
  npm install mime
  ```
- create a rawConnectionHandler to serve the assets (credits to: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20358612)
  server/static_files_handler.coffee

  ```
  fs = Npm.require('fs')
  mime = Npm.require('mime')
  WebApp.rawConnectHandlers.use (req, res, next) ->
    re = /^\/static\/(.*)$/.exec(req.url)
    if re isnt null # Only handle URLs that start with /static/*
      filePath = process.env.PWD + "/public/.#static/" + re[1]
      type = mime.lookup(filePath)
      data = fs.readFileSync(filePath, data)
      res.writeHead 200,
        "Content-Type": type

      res.write data
      res.end()
    else # Other urls will have default behaviors
      next()
    return
  ```

Limitations of this approach:

- not suitable to serve assets with query parameters. The regex would also match /static/html/image.html?src=/static/img/cat.png trying to serve a file with the filename including the parameters. This is easy to change.
- Meteor is completely unaware of the files, they therefore don't get included into the appcache manifest. If you want to make them available offline, check out the addPaths option I added to https://github.com/buildhybrid/appcache-extra

If you don't want to work around the problems, consider serving the assets from an external service (ex. AWS S3).

Comment: there is a problem if you will go and deploy this app on *.meter.com - this will cause an error - thats because of Meteor ignores (and actually have no) .#static directory

Answer (score 2):

This is a big issue for large scale applications built in Meteor. I talked to Matt over at Meteor, and he said that their team is working on a solution to this problem for one of their upcoming releases. So get on their newsletter, and you'll be notified when it is available.

Mathieu, your comment:

> I finally found a workaround. I'm putting everything in /public/lib/. Then, line 286 of /usr/lib/meteor/app/run.js, I'm adding the folder I don't want Meteor to watch: self.exclude_paths = [ path.join(app_dir, '.meteor', 'local'), path.join(app_dir, 'public', 'lib') ]; This way I can have as much files as I want in lib, and they don't slow everything down. include path is '/lib/dojo/dojo.js'.

is a good hack for now, and here are the other issues that relate that will also be covered in the upcoming release:

- Some packages have overlapping dependencies, but do not exclude them like in PHP's  require_once().
- A native require / define dynamic script loader, so not all files are loaded on entry one that can calculate dependency order without having to go levels, lib or main.*
- An official way to create and deploy packages to a repository. Currently it is using [Meteorite](https://github.com/oortcloud/meteorite) (mrt) and [Atmosphere](https://github.com/oortcloud/atmosphere).

Comment: The goal is to have meteor serve but not watch the asset files in a directory, preferably all the large video files I have in public. Does your exclude_paths line continue to serve the files?