# Meteor method call looping

Tags: javascript, android, meteor

**Short Story:**

Meteor method loops if the method executed in more than 120 seconds.

This is how I tested

There is Meteor method called 'build' in server side as below:

```
'build': function(buildRequest) {

  log.info('method build get called: buildRequest=%s', JSON.stringify(buildRequest));

  shell.exec('echo "simulate long Android build task."');
  shell.exec('sleep ' + buildRequest.sec);

  var result = {'successful': true, 'output': "OK", 'fileName': 'test.apk', 'genFile': '/tmp/test.apk'}

  log.info("method return result=%s", JSON.stringify(result));
  return result;
}
```

I set route to call this method as below:

```
this.route('buildApp', {
  where: 'server'
  , action: function() {
    var buildRequest = this.request.query;
    log.info('buildApp: http parameters: ', buildRequest);

    var result = methods.build(buildRequest);
    var response = this.response;

    if (result.successful) {
      methods.download(response, result.genFile, result.fileName);
    }
    else {
      response.writeHead(500, {});
      response.end("server has error: " + result.output);
    }
  }
})
```

Then, I call url

`http://localhost:3000/buildApp?app=test&server=dev&db=DB&appId=test&sec=120`

then, build method loops

```
=> App running at: http://localhost:3000/
I20150109-14:55:45.285(9)? info: buildApp: http parameters:  app=test, server=dev, db=DB, appId=test, sec=120
I20150109-14:55:45.358(9)? info: method build get called: buildRequest={"app":"test","server":"dev","db":"DB","appId":"test","sec":"120"}
I20150109-14:55:45.358(9)? simulate long Android build task.
I20150109-14:57:45.359(9)? info: method return result={"successful":true,"output":"OK","fileName":"test.apk","genFile":"/tmp/test.apk"}
I20150109-14:57:45.387(9)? info: buildApp: http parameters:  app=test, server=dev, db=DB, appId=test, sec=120
I20150109-14:57:45.387(9)? info: method build get called: buildRequest={"app":"test","server":"dev","db":"DB","appId":"test","sec":"120"}
I20150109-14:57:45.446(9)? simulate long Android build task.
```

I assume it is related this code:

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/096df9d62dc9c3d560d31b546365f6bdab5a87dc/packages/webapp/webapp_server.js#L18

**Long story:**

I made a simple android app build screen with `Meteor`.
Everything works well however if I submit the form to build app, it builds over and over again. even if I stop server and restart, as soon as server restarted it calls again.

If form filled and submitted, I call `Meteor` 'build' method.
The method will clone git repository and build the app by calling shell script below.

```
var exec = shell.exec('./genApp.sh ' + buildRequest.appId + " " + buildRequest.server + " " + buildRequest.db);
//var exec = shell.exec('echo "simple task will not loop"');
```

If I call `./genApp.sh` (it will take a few minutes.), then the Meteor 'build' method looping itself. but if I do simple task, it will not loop but executed once.

I added below code at the beginning of build Meteor method to stop it for debugging. But I have no idea what causes this.

```
      if (a == 1) {
        a = 0;
        throw new Error("Why call again?!");
      }
      ++ a;
```

the server log:

```
I20150108-19:48:08.220(9)? info: success
I20150108-19:48:08.221(9)? info: return result=[object Object]
I20150108-19:48:09.034(9)? Exception while invoking method 'build' Error: Why call again?!
I20150108-19:48:09.035(9)?     at [object Object].methods.build (app/javis.js:92:25)
I20150108-19:48:09.035(9)?     at maybeAuditArgumentChecks (packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:1599:1)
I20150108-19:48:09.035(9)?     at packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:648:1
I20150108-19:48:09.035(9)?     at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:56:1)
I20150108-19:48:09.035(9)?     at packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:647:1
I20150108-19:48:09.035(9)?     at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:56:1)
I20150108-19:48:09.036(9)?     at [object Object]._.extend.protocol_handlers.method (packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:646:1)
I20150108-19:48:09.036(9)?     at packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:546:1
```

main source code

```
var APP_01 = 'app01-andy';
var APP_02 = 'app02-andy';

if (Meteor.isClient) {

  Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate: 'layout'
  })
  Router.map(function() {
    this.route('/', 'home');
  });

  buildRequest = {
    appId: 0
    , server: 'dev'
    , db: 'DEFAULT'
    , app: APP_01
  };

  Session.set('successful',  false);
  Session.set('output', '');
  Session.set('downloadLink', null);

  Template.home.helpers({
    successful: function() {
      return Session.get('successful');
    }
    , output: function() {
      return Session.get('output');
    }
    , downloadLink: function() {
      var successful = Session.get('successful');
      var downloadLink = Session.get('downloadLink');
      console.log(downloadLink);
      if (successful) {
        $('#downloadLink').show();
      } else {
        $('#downloadLink').hide();
      }
      return downloadLink;
    }
  });

  Template.home.events({
    'submit .app-build-form': function() {
      event.preventDefault();

      buildRequest.appId = event.target.appId.value;
      buildRequest.server = event.target.server.value;
      buildRequest.db = event.target.db.value;
      buildRequest.app = event.target.app.value;

      $("#submit").prop('disabled', true);

      Meteor.call('build', buildRequest, function(error, result) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
        Session.set('successful', result.successful);
        Session.set('output', result.output);
        Session.set('downloadLink', '/downloadApp?fullPathFile='+result.genFile+'&fileName='+result.fileName);
        $("#submit").prop('disabled', false);
        console.log("meteor call end");
      });

      console.log("submit finished");
      // prevent default form submit.
      return false;
    },
    'click #sel_app': function() {
      console.log(event.target.value);
      var app = event.target.value;
      var selDb = $("#sel_db");
      if (app === APP_02) {
        selDb.val('APP_02_DB'); selDb.prop('disabled', true);
      }
      else {
        selDb.prop('disabled', false);
      }
    }
  });
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {

  var shell = Meteor.npmRequire('shelljs');
  var log = Meteor.npmRequire('winston');

  var a = 0;

  var methods = {
    'build': function(buildRequest) {
      if (a == 1) {
        a = 0;
        throw new Error("Why call again?!");
      }
      ++ a;
      log.info(JSON.stringify(buildRequest));
      var dir = shell.pwd();
      log.info("work dir: %s", dir);

      shell.cd('/project/build/');

      var branch = null;
      var app = buildRequest.app;
      if (app === APP_01) {
        branch = '2.0';
      }
      else if (app === APP_02) {
        branch = '1.0';
      }
      else {
        branch = 'master';
      }
      shell.exec('rm -rf ' + buildRequest.app);
      shell.exec('git clone -b '+branch+' ssh://git@company-build.com/'+buildRequest.app+'.git');
      shell.cd(buildRequest.app + "/app");

      var exec = shell.exec('./genApp.sh ' + buildRequest.appId + " " + buildRequest.server + " " + buildRequest.db);
      //var exec = shell.exec('echo "simple task will not loop"');

      var code = exec.code;
      var output = exec.output;

      log.info(code);
      log.info(output);

      var fileName = null;
      var matches = output.match(/The package copied to (.+apk)/);
      var genFile = null;
      if (matches != null && matches.length > 1) {
        genFile = matches[1];
        log.info(genFile);
        // TODO : do not write file in public, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13201723/generating-and-serving-static-files-with-meteor
        /*
        shell.mkdir(process.env.PWD + '/tmp');
        shell.cp('-f', genFile, process.env.PWD + '/tmp');
        */
        fileName = genFile.substring(genFile.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
      }
      matches = output.match(/BUILD SUCCESSFUL/);
      var successful = false;
      if (matches != null && matches.length > 0) {
        log.info("success");
        successful = true;
      }

      var result = {'successful': successful, 'output': output, 'fileName': fileName, 'genFile': genFile};

      log.info("return result="+result);
      return result;
    }
    , 'download' : function(response, fullPathFile, fileName) {

      var stat = fs.statSync(fullPathFile);
      response.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.android.package-archive'
        , 'Content-Length': stat.size
        , 'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename=' + fileName
      });
      fs.createReadStream(result.genFile).pipe(response);
    }
  };

  Meteor.methods(methods);

  fs = Npm.require('fs');

  Router.map(function() {
    this.route('buildApp', {
      where: 'server'
      , action: function() {
        var buildRequest = this.request.query;
        log.info(this.request.query);
        log.info(buildRequest);
        var result = methods.build(buildRequest);
        var response = this.response;

        if (result.successful) {
          methods.download(response, result.genFile, result.fileName);
        }
        else {
          response.writeHead(500, {});
          response.end("server has error: " + result.output);
        }
      }
    }),
    this.route('downloadApp', {
      where: 'server'
      , action: function() {
        var params = this.request.query;
        var fullPathFile = params.fullPathFile;
        var fileName = params.fileName;
        methods.download(this.response, fullPathFile, fileName);
      }
    })
  });

  Meteor.startup(function () {
    // code to run on server at startup
  });
}
```

What causes the loop? Any help will be appreciated.

Even I call `http://localhost:3000/buildApp?app=xxx&server=live&db=DB&appId=12423` , the build loops.

OK if I change `./genApp.sh` to simple one to narrow the conditions.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "test"
echo "The package copied to /service/release/20150108/existing-file.apk"
echo "BUILD SUCCESSFUL"

sleep 180
```

It calls again when it sleeps 180 seconds. What make this call again? because I call the url directly. I think there is no client side code retrial.

Comment: Hmm.. So you're extracting files to your project directory? The changing files would cause a "hot-code-push" which would cause currently "not finished" methods to be re-run after meteor reloads (or your browser to try again because it didn't receive a response). A quick test is to put them under a folder with a `~` at the end of the name.

Comment: I copied generated file into "public" directory but I know that is not good way so I do not copy it and read and write it when server get called /downloadApp?fileName=xxx, so I assume there is no hot-code-push, now but still reload happends.

Comment: what directory are you reading/writing in?

Comment: I don't read and write now, but it loops. please see my edits(short story) in question.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm... it could be that when `shell.exec` is run synchronously it "starves the event loop", causing some issues.

The solution would be to use a `Future` which would allow Meteor to continue running in another `Fiber` while waiting for `shell.exec` to complete.

```
var Future = Npm.require('fibers/future');

Meteor.methods({
'build': function(buildRequest) {
  var fut = new Future(), result;
  log.info('method build get called: buildRequest=%s', JSON.stringify(buildRequest));

  shell.exec('echo "simulate long Android build task."');
  shell.exec('sleep ' + buildRequest.sec, function(code, output){
    fut.return([code, output]);
  });
  result = fut.wait();
  log.info(result[0], result[1])

  var result = {'successful': true, 'output': "OK", 'fileName': 'test.apk', 'genFile': '/tmp/test.apk'}

  log.info("method return result=%s", JSON.stringify(result));
  return result;
}
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it is same thing, it loops call, never writes a file. I think it is because internally if the Meteor methods runs more than 120 seconds it calls again through websocket?!. Therefore if some task takes longer than 120 seconds, it should be implemented different way, I am a earth man who does not explored Meteor world much. So not knowing exact solution for this in a Meteor way. however I assume that publish/subscribe model can be one way. or Is there a way call server method(a Meteor method) asynchronously?

Comment: Hmm.. I'll try out some testing later. Anecdotally, I have some methods that call web-services and take quite a while to complete; so it would be strange if there were such a limit. Additionally, the answer given here is still important - don't use long running sync functions, unless they're compatible with fibers/futures.

Comment: @Chk0nDanger The Meteor Source you pointed to only appears to be for `HTTP` requests - not for calls to `Meteor.methods`; It will probably work for Method calls. But I'll post another answer anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Fool proof way to make this work:

1. Create a Collection to store "Build Requests"
2. Set a timer to occasionally process build requests in a separate Fiber.
3. Notify users of "completed" build requests with yet another collection and publication.

Here's an example of how that might be structured [not bug tested]:

```
"use strict";

var fs, shell, log, Future;
// need a collection to store build requests & their status
var Builds = new Mongo.Collection('builds');
var APP_01 = 'app01-andy';
var APP_02 = 'app02-andy';

// expose routes to client & server
Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: 'layout'
});
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('/', 'home');
  this.route('downloadApp', {
    where: 'server'
    , action: function() {
      var params = this.request.query,
          buildId = params.buildId,
          build, stat;
      check(buildId, String); // or Mongo Identifier
      build = Builds.findOne({_id: buildId});
      check(build, Match.ObjectIncluding({
        file: String,
        fileName: String
      }));
      stat = fs.statSync(build.file);
      this.response.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.android.package-archive'
        , 'Content-Length': stat.size
        , 'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename=' + build.fileName
      });
      fs.createReadStream(build.file).pipe(this.response);
    }
  });
});
if (Meteor.isClient) {

  Session.set('currentBuildId', null);
  Session.set('submittingBuildRequest', false);

  Tracker.autorun(function(){
    // Whenever there is a current build set, subscribe to it.
    var buildId = Session.get('currentBuildId');
    if (buildId != null){
      Meteor.subscribe('build', buildId);
    }
  });

  Template.home.helpers({
    // Use this helper in your template to expose the `state` property (queued, running, success, failed)
    currentBuild: function() {
      var buildId = Session.get('currentBuildId'), build;
      if (buildId == null) return null;
      build = Builds.findOne({_id: buildId});
      if (build == null) return null;
      return build;
    }
  });

  Template.home.events({
    'submit .app-build-form': function(e) {
      var target, buildRequest;
      e.preventDefault();
      target = e.target;

      buildRequest = {
        appId: target.appId.value
        , server: target.server.value
        , db: target.db.value
        , app: target.app.value
      };
      Session.set('submittingBuildRequest', true);

      Meteor.call('requestBuild', buildRequest, function(error, buildId) {
        Session.set('submittingBuildRequest', false);
        if (error != null){
           console.error(error);
        } else {
          console.log("buildId=", JSON.stringify(buildId));
          Session.set('currentBuildId', buildId);
        }
      });
    },
    'click #sel_app': function(e) {
      var app = e.target.value;
      var selDb = $("#sel_db");
      if (app === APP_02) {
        selDb.val('APP_02_DB'); selDb.prop('disabled', true);
      }
      else {
        selDb.prop('disabled', false);
      }
    },
    'click a.downloadCurrentBuild': function(){
      // Alternatively, could create a download url with the "pathFor" template helper
      Router.go('downloadApp', {buildId: Session.get('currentBuildId')})
    }
  });
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  fs = Npm.require('fs');
  shell = Meteor.npmRequire('shelljs');
  log = Meteor.npmRequire('winston');
  Future = Npm.require('fibers/future');

  Meteor.publish({
    'build': function(buildId){
      check(buildId, String); // or Mongo Identifier
      return Builds.find({_id: buildId}, {fields: {
        fileName: false, // don't expose real paths to client
        file: false
      }});
    }
  });

  Meteor.methods({
    'requestBuild': function(buildRequest){
      check(buildRequest, {
        appId: Match.Integer,
        server: String, // apply additional restrictions
        db: String, // apply additional restrictions
        app: Match.OneOf(APP_01, APP_02)
      });

      _.extend(buildRequest, {
        state: 'queued'
        // These properties will be set later, just keeping them here for reference
        //, output: null
        //, fileName: null
        //, file: null
      });

      return Builds.insert(buildRequest);
    }
  });


  var Builder = {
    // Alternative: Poll the database for new builds
    //run: function Builder_Run() {
    //  log.info('checking for "queued" builds');
    //  // may need to change this to `fetch` and then loop manually
    //  Builds.find({state: 'queued'}).forEach(Builder.processBuildRequest);
    //  Meteor.setTimeout(Builder.run, 1000); // tail call to run again (after 1 second)
    //},
    exec: function(cmd){
      // Wraps shell.exec so that they don't block the event loop
      var fut = new Future();
      shell.exec(cmd, function(code, output){
        fut.return({code: code, output: output});
      });
      return fut.wait();
    },
    processBuildRequest: function Builder_processBuildRequest(buildRequest) {
      console.log('running buildRequest=', JSON.stringify(buildRequest));
      Builds.update({_id: buildRequest._id}, {
        $set: {
          state: 'running'
        }
      });

      var branch = null;
      if (buildRequest.ap === APP_01) {
        branch = '2.0';
      }
      else if (buildRequest.ap === APP_02) {
        branch = '1.0';
      }
      else {
        branch = 'master';
      }

      shell.cd('/project/build/');
      Builder.exec('rm -rf ' + buildRequest.app);
      Builder.exec('git clone -b ' + branch + ' ssh://git@company-build.com/' + buildRequest.app + '.git');
      shell.cd(buildRequest.app + "/app");
      //var exec = Builder.exec('./genApp.sh ' + buildRequest.appId + " " + buildRequest.server + " " + buildRequest.db)
      var exec = Builder.exec('sleep 180');
      var output = exec.output;

      log.info("code=" + exec.code);
      log.info("output=" + output);

      var fileName = null;
      var matches = output.match(/The package copied to (.+apk)/);
      var file = null;
      if (matches != null && matches.length > 1) {
        file = matches[1];
        log.info("file=" + file);
        fileName = file.substring(file.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
      }
      matches = output.match(/BUILD SUCCESSFUL/);

      if (matches != null && matches.length > 0) {
        log.info("success");
        Builds.update({_id: buildRequest._id}, {
          $set: {
            state: 'success',
            file: file,
            fileName: fileName,
            output: output
          }
        });
      } else {
        log.info("failed");
        Builds.update({_id: buildRequest._id}, {
          $set: {
            state: 'failed'
          }
        });
      }
    }
  };


  Meteor.startup(function () {
    // code to run on server at startup

    // if using polling method
    //Meteor.setTimeout(Builder.run, 1000); // will poll for new builds every second (unless already running a build)

    // set up an observe [to run forever] to automatically process new builds.
    Builds.find({state: 'queued'}).observe({
      added: Builder.processBuildRequest
    });
  });
}
```