# Cannot request Iron Router server route twice without refreshing the client

Tags: node.js, meteor, iron-router

I am calling a meteor method, which generates a file using [fs](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html). I wait for a callback giving me the path where the file exists, and then I request the file with a server route. The code is very similar to [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13201723/generating-and-serving-static-files-with-meteor/20358612#20358612). I have also tried using [createReadStream](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options) (as demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21565991/how-to-serve-a-file-using-iron-router-or-meteor-itself/21566476#21566476)) instead of passing the file directly to `response.write`.

This all works well on the client's first click of my export/download button. However, if for some reason they want to click the button more than once, the file will get generated but the file will not get served by Iron Router. There are no errors on the client or server. If the user refreshes the client, then the feature will work again (once).

**Why do I need to refresh the browser in order to request the same server route a second time?** Am I doing something wrong?

---

**[Example Application](https://github.com/micahalcorn/ir-server-route-download)**

Comment: hard to say without seeing the code.

Comment: @ChristianFritz please see edit with link to example app, thx.

Comment: Does the URL change when they click the first download? If so, and the second route is the same, you will not get redirected as you are already there. If this is the case, you can use the router hooks to send the user back to the route they came from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does the URL change when they click the first download? If so, and the second route is the same, you will not get redirected as you are already there. If this is the case, can you use the router hooks to send the user back to the route they came from?

Comment: Thanks, @FloatingCoder, that seems to be the case. I am able to download the file repeatedly if I make the file name (& route param) dynamic. I don't seem to be able to Router.go to a client route from the server route's onAfterAction hook though. I'm not sure that I need to redirect, but it would be nice to know if that is possible.