# Turn off file watching in Meteor

Tags: javascript, multithreading, meteor

I am building an app that stores user generated images.  These images get used throughout the app in a gallery type view.  They also update/regenerate frequently.

The problem I am having is when a new image gets generated, I am storing it in the public directory. This causes the meteor server to "restart".

Is there a way to turn off file watching?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to prevent Meteor from watching files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11504883/how-to-prevent-meteor-from-watching-files)

Comment: How did you even manage to ask this without finding the duplicate and the link to https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/437

Comment: @mplungjan - well, it didn't pop up while typing the question.  I did see many similar questions later, but none of them had a good answer, so I left it up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up exporting the file to an S3 bucket so that it didn't effect the Meteor watching.

Answer (score 2):

1. I don't think it is possible as for now
2. Even if you could stop to watch it would not solve your issue

When meteor detect a change it rebuild the server (.meteor/local/build/) and serve it from there.

Public folder is sent there : ".meteor/local/build/static/"

In a case where you would stop watching for updates you would also stop to see changes in what your client can access.

I found out that this particular case can be solved by replacing meteor by another tool to deal with static assets.

I have a meteor app to deal with data and file sync, but I also keep an Apache to serve as a file distribution manager.

My meteor app keep small, assets can be sent somewhere else (Ex.: S3 when you get in production).

Answer (score 1):

I just found an answer on a similar question on this website that I think might help if you haven't found a solution yet.

> I finally found a workaround. I'm putting everything in /public/lib/.
>   Then, line 286 of /usr/lib/meteor/app/run.js, I'm adding the folder I
>   don't want Meteor to watch: self.exclude_paths = [ path.join(app_dir,
>   '.meteor', 'local'), path.join(app_dir, 'public', 'lib') ]; This way I
>   can have as much files as I want in lib, and they don't slow
>   everything down. include path is '/lib/dojo/dojo.js'.

by [Mathieu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1528917/mathieu)

Comment: As for 2023, can't make it work. 
I can't find `/usr/lib/meteor/app/run.js`; my Meteor runs from `/home/user/.meteor`, hope it is proper folder.
But I can't locate app/run.js and can't grep the "exclude_paths" line.

Answer (score 0):

I like to use develop mode for small-mid project as well,
saving files to /public is terrible idea.

Recommand [Meteor-Files](https://github.com/veliovgroup/Meteor-Files)
Save all files like json data into the mongodb or s3,
and use it like the file you have in local.