# How avoid changes in folder triggering reload of app

Tags: meteor

I’m saving images into the app/files folder using CollectionFS. How can I avoid Meteor thinking it has to reload the application everytime an image is added to the folder?

I’ve tried naming the folder files~ but it did not work.

Comment: See https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/437 & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11504883/how-to-prevent-meteor-from-watching-files/25161820#25161820

Comment: Probably, you shouldn't save dynamic files in your project directory anyway.