# Upload and access to images on server with nginx and meteor

Tags: url, meteor, nginx, file-upload, directory

I have a Meteor application deployed with nginx.
I try to upload images from the application to save the images on the server. When I'm in localhost, I save my images in the `myapp/public/uploads` folder. But, when I deploy, this folder become `myapp/bundle/programs/web.browser/app/uploads`. So, when I upload an image, it saved in a new folder in myapp/public/uploads. But so, I can't access to it. When I'm in localhost I access to my images like that : `localhost:3000/uploads/myImage.png` but when I do `myAdress/uploads/myImage.png` I access to the `myapp/bundle/programs/web.browser/app/uploads` folder and not the one where the images are saved (`myapp/public/uploads`).

This is my code to save images :

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
  UploadServer.init({
    tmpDir: process.env.PWD + '/app/uploads',
    uploadDir: process.env.PWD + '/app/uploads',
    checkCreateDirectories: true,
    uploadUrl: '/upload',
    // *** For renaming files on server
    getFileName: function(file, formData) {
      //CurrentUserId is a variable passed from publications.js
      var name = file.name;
      name = name.replace(/\s/g, '');
      return currentTileId + "_"  + name;
    },
    finished: function(fileInfo, formFields) {
      var name = fileInfo.name;
      name = name.replace(/\s/g, '');
      insertionImages(name, currentTileId, docId);
    },
  });
});
```

So, do you know how can I do to save and access to my images when the application is deployed ? Maybe save the image in the `myapp/bundle/programs/web.browser/app/uploads` folder or access to the `myapp/public/uploads` folder with an url.

Comment: for this and other reasons, my team quickly switched to Cloudinary for uploading user images. lots of advantages to using a provider rather than your own server, and Cloudinary (though a PITA at times) does provide a pretty handy service. we use a Meteor package to help manage image operations: https://github.com/Lepozepo/cloudinary

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I prefer to keep my own server.

Comment: Understood. I'm curious to see the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what we do.

**Use an external dir** for uploads, say, `/var/uploads`. Keeping the uploads in `public` folder makes the meteor app to reload in the dev environment, on any file upload.

Now, at local, use Meteor to serve these files at a certain url. In production, use nginx to serve the same at the same url.

### For Development

1) **Symlink your upload dir to a hidden folder in public**.

eg:

```
ln -s /var/uploads /path/to/public/.#static
```

2) **Serve** the public hidden folder **via Meteor** by using:

The url `/static` will server the folder `public/.#static` by using the following code on the server. Ref: [How to prevent Meteor from watching files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11504883/how-to-prevent-meteor-from-watching-files/25161820#25161820)

```
var fs = require('fs'), mime = require('mime');

WebApp.rawConnectHandlers.use(function(req, res, next) {

    var data, filePath, re, type;
    re = /^\/static\/(.*)$/.exec(req.url);
    if (re !== null) {
        filePath = process.env.PWD + '/public/.#static/' + re[1];
        try {
            stats = fs.lstatSync(filePath);
            if (stats.isFile()) {
                type = mime.lookup(filePath);
                data = fs.readFileSync(filePath, data);
                res.writeHead(200, {
                    'Content-Type': type
                });
                res.write(data);
                res.end();
            }
        }
        catch (e) {
            // console.error(filePath, "not found", e); // eslint-disable-line no-console
            next();
        }
    }
    else {
        next();
    }
});
```

### For production

1) Use **nginx** for serving the upload dir

```
server {
   ...
   location /static/ {
      root /var/uploads;
   }
   ...
}
```

That's it. `/static` will server the content of your uploads dir i.e. `/var/uploads`